# `\futurelet` how to get the replacement macro for `\UTFviii@three@octets`?

Tags: pdftex, unicode, newunicodechar

I want to use `\futurelet` to test the following token. Towards this end I have a setup that looks like the following:

```tex
\makeatletter
\def\@ExpandSub{%
    \typeout{Given Input: \meaning\@input}%
    \typeout{Followup command: \meaning\@following}%

    \ifx\@following\UTFviii@three@octets%  <--- doesn't work!
        \typeout{>>> That's unicode!}%
    \else%
        \typeout{>>> That's NOT unicode...}%
    \fi%
}

\protected\def\sub#1{%
    \let\@input#1%
    \futurelet\@following\@ExpandSub%
}
\makeatother
```

1. How can I test if the next token is a Unicode character `\ifx\@following\UTFviii@three@octets` doesn't work, I think because `\@following` holds a protected macro that holds `\UTFviii@three@octets` instead of `\UTFviii@three@octets` itself. The logs say: `Followup command: \protected macro:->\UTFviii@three@octets �`, but I want the replacement macro as it was specified inside `\newunicodechar` instead.
2. If this is the case, how can I get the substitute macro, as defined by `\newunicodechar`?

This is an attempt to implement [Automatically combine unicode double subscripts aᵢⱼ = a_{i}_{j} as a_{ij}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649550).

Full Demo

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}


\makeatletter
\newtoggle{insub}
\def\@ExpandSub{%
    \typeout{Given Input: \meaning\@input}%
    \typeout{Followup command: \meaning\@following}%

    % if \@following is \UTFviii@three@octets, get the replacement text
    \ifx\@following\UTFviii@three@octets%  <--- doesn't work!
        \typeout{>>> That's unicode!}%
    \else%
        \typeout{>>> That's NOT unicode...}%
        \let\@actual\@following
    \fi%

    \iftoggle{insub}{
        \@input%
    }{
        \toggletrue{insub}%
        \sb\bgroup\@input%
    }%
    \ifx\@actual\sub%
        \typeout{keep going!}%
    \else%
        \typeout{Stop!}%
        \egroup\togglefalse{insub}%
    \fi%
}

% \DeclareRobustCommand*{\sub}[1]{\futurelet\@following\@ExpandSub{#1}}
\protected\def\sub#1{%
    \let\@input#1%
    \futurelet\@following\@ExpandSub%
}
\makeatother


\AtBeginDocument{
\newunicodechar{ᵢ}{\sub{i}}
\newunicodechar{ⱼ}{\sub{j}}
\newunicodechar{ₖ}{\sub{k}}
\newunicodechar{ₗ}{\sub{l}}
\newunicodechar{ₘ}{\sub{m}}
\newunicodechar{ₙ}{\sub{n}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
$a_{ijklmn}$ \\
%$a\chain{i}\chain{j}\chain{k}\chain{l}\chain{m}\chain{n}$ \\
$a\sub{i}\sub{j}\sub{k}\sub{l}\sub{m}\sub{n}$ \\
% $a\sub[i]\sub[j]\sub[k]\sub[l]\sub[m]\sub[n]$ \\
$aᵢⱼₖₗₘₙ$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Related:

- [Expansion rule for a character redefined with `\newunicodechar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649571/expansion-rule-for-a-character-redefined-with-newunicodechar)
- [A Question About \futurelet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474451/a-question-about-futurelet)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to test if the next byte is one of (the leading byte of) ᵢⱼₖₗₘₙ?  It is very hard to expand `\@following` while it could be a unicode byte as well as primitive commands such  as `\mathrm` or `\kern`.

Comment: Quick note: I implement this in one of my libraries https://github.com/user202729/TeXlib/blob/main/unicode-math-input.sty#L505-L541 . Basically, first test if the following token is a N-type, if it is grab the next byte, set escapechar to something nonempty, test the stringfication of it to see if it consist of one character, if yes then branch over the character value to determine how many octet to grab. --- Although of course there are different ways as well. --- To get the inner macro, it's stored in e.g. `\csname u8:α\endcsname` for the character `α`.

Comment: apart from the futurelet question why  `\let\@input#1` ??? This undefines `\input` not even within a group, did you intend that?